# Keep currentItem of ViewPager when dataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, commonsware-cwac

I'm using [android.support.v4.view.ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with [cwac-pager](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager) to add or remove Fragments dynamically. Also this `ViewPager` has negative `PageMargin` and [LayoutTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html) (for API >= 11) animates for `DISAPPEARING`, `CHANGE_APPEARING`, `CHANGE_DISAPPEARING`. In layout, there is a `Button` calls `mPagerAdapter.insert(pageDescriptor, mViewPager.getCurrentItem())` on click. When I click it, position of `mViewPager` automatically increases, so new page appears at the left of the current page. But I want to make new page appear at the center of screen.

I looked into the `ViewPager` [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-4.4.2_r2/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java), and I think this part causing problem:

```
void dataSetChanged() {
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
        final ItemInfo ii = mItems.get(i);
        final int newPos = mAdapter.getItemPosition(ii.object);
        ...
        if (ii.position != newPos) {
            if (ii.position == mCurItem) {
                // Our current item changed position. Follow it.
                newCurrItem = newPos;
            }

            ii.position = newPos;
            needPopulate = true;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The ideal scenario is:

1. Click the add button
2. `notifyDataSetChanged()` called without changes of `mViewPager.getCurrentItem()`
3. Animation of `CHANGE_APPEARING`
4. New page appears at the center of screen

Comment: I have no idea how you would accomplish what you seek, sorry.